# Binding error on WPF (biding to DataContext)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

First of all let me say that I'm rather new to WPF, so excuse me for any silly mistakes, but I've been cracking my head at this for a while now.

I have a simple sollution with three classes:

```
public class MyCustomItem

public class MyCustomLayout : ThirdPartyLayout<MyCustomItem>

public class MyViewController : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

MyCustomItem is a simple class with some properties ("Name" being one of them). ThirdPartyLayoutTool is a generic component inside an SDK that inherits from System.Windows.Controls.Panel. And MyViewController is the view controller I'm using as a data content.

I then created this simple XAML as the projects main window:

```
<Window x:Class="DependencyViewer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sdk="clr-namespace:Sdk;assembly=Sdk"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">


    <local:MyCustomLayout x:Name="myLayout"/>
</Window>
```

Everything displays accordingly.Now my objective is to enhance the display of one of the sub components that is displayed by the ThirdPartyLayout panel, called TargetControl. So I add the following code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type sdk:TargetControl}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <ToolTip x:Key="ToolTipContent">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Testing 1 2 3"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource ToolTipContent}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

When I run the code, the "Testing 1 2 3" message appears correctly, however, I don't see the Name property. On the output window, I get the following message:

`BindingExpression path error: 'Name' property not found on 'object' ''MyViewController' (HashCode=31884011)'`

What I don't get is why the binding is happening on the MyViewController class, instead of TargetControl class. Any ideas?

Best regards,
Carlos Jourdan

EDIT:

After tinkering guide mainly by the recommendations given by newb, I eventually found out that the source of the error is in fact in the SDK. The current release is still faulty, but when compiling from source I get the expected behavior.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a binding in XAML, you are, by default, binding to the current DataContext. In this isntance, it seems that `MyViewController` is the DataContext of the `sdk:TargetControl`. To bind to the `Name` property of the `skd:TargetControl` instead, try the following:

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type sdk:TargetControl}}}"/>
```

Comment: This seems to be in the right direction. Using RelativeSource ={RelativeSource Self}} still throws an error because it tries to bind to the TextControl. Using RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent} makes the error disappear in the output, however, the binding still doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user1139216 I was in a hurry and goofed the target. Try the edit, if you please.

Comment: With the edit I get the error in the output: "Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='skd:TargetControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=Name"

Comment: But as I pointed out, the {RelativeSource TemplatedParent} alternative appears to work, as there are no errors on the output. However I don't see any data displayed where it should be.

Comment: I see. The fact that it's part of a style must be why `TemplatedParent` is required. Do you just see the "Testing 1 2 3" or no `ToolTip` at all?

Comment: I eventually found out that the source of the error is in fact in the SDK. The current release is still faulty, but when compiling from source I get the expected behavior.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like DataContext of xaml.cs of MyViewController has the reference of MyCustomItem.

If you want you can set in xaml.cs, MyCustomLayout.ItemsSource = this.DataContext.

Or you can do MyCustomLayout.ItemsSource = specific property of MyCustomItem.

Comment: I'm giving this a +1 because it did have some relation to the problem that was corrected on the SDK, but I'm setting the answer to newb because it was what pointed me in the right direciton.